# How do you get the fully qualified class name of the type in a generic function?

Tags: vb.net, generics

Suppose I want to write a generic function that will return the fully qualified name of the data type. In other words, how would you implement the following:

```
Public Shared Function Foo(Of T)() As String
    ' Return the fully qualified name of T
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the GetType "method":

```
Console.WriteLine(GetType(T));
```